# get back to the same page as when you left with paginator

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I go back to a list view of records that uses paginator and get it to  display a certain page?

```
For example
1)I am at list_view which displays a list of records. 
2) I go to page 2
3) I click a record and get taken to another page to see the details of this record
4) I click back link and I am back at the list view BUT I am on page 1 and 
 I want to be on page 2
```

What is the current method to go back to a list view at the same page as when you left it?Do I need session variable ?

```
//controller    list view 
 $this->Paginator->settings = array(
             'conditions' => array(
             'TutorRequest.tutor_id' => $tutorId, 
             'TutorRequest.type' => 'meeting'),
             'limit' => 2  );

            $meetings = $this->Paginator->paginate('TutorRequest');
            $this->set('meetings', $meetings);

 //view of 1 item and want to go back to the list view
 echo  ..'Back', array(
         'controller' => 'lessons',  'action' => 'dashboard4', //back to same page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the record details page sending the page where you are via url: "detailsPage.php?id=123&page=2" and build there the back button: "recordsPage.php?page=2"

Comment: Is there a way to get the actual value in the form of 'page=no'?

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. You can give whatever value you want to a url variable.

Comment: Ok and this is how I get the page number $this->Paginator->counter(array('format' => ('{:page}') ));

Answer (score 1):

Lets just say that you have contacts and you go to page 2. In your contacts controller you have a method called view. In this method you do the following

```
public function view($id){

   //some code
   $this->set('refer', $this->referer());
}
```

at your view you create a link

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Back'), $refer);
```

or you can just do this

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Back'), $this->request->referer());
```

Check this:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeRequest::referer